# Eppleton tileengine missing libraries. net.java.canvas.GraphicsContext

Tags: java, javafx, shared-libraries, tile-engine

Im trying to run Eppletons JavaFX tileengine but there is a library missing i can't find.

net.java.html.canvas.GraphicsContext

Web --> http://jayskills.com/blog/2013/01/09/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx/

Link to his GIT Repo --> https://github.com/eppleton/FXGameEngine

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fount it !!!

Its one of Eppletons own Projects.
Just insert this Project as a dependency! -> https://github.com/eppleton/canvas/commit/30724e61bdb5eb4e955b865c88299da3dbdf2840
This commit is needed because the newer versions are not campatible with the game endgine.
(check the dates of the last commits in the gameengine an the canvas project)

This library is missing too in some files but can be found by searching for maven repositories(netbeans).

```
import org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider;
```

Hope i could help somone!
I wrote a ticket in his gitrepo. I hope he will fix it.

Link to the reported issue:

https://github.com/eppleton/FXGameEngine/issues/5